# Remove languages other than English from corpus or data frame in R

Tags: r, inner-join, text-mining, sentiment-analysis, tm

I am currently looking to perform some text mining on 25000 YouTube comments, which I gathered using the `tuber` package. I am very new to coding and with all these different information out there, this can be a bit overwhelming at times. So I already cleaned my corpus, that I created:

```
# Build a corpus, and specify the source to be character vectors
corpus <- Corpus(VectorSource(comments_final$textOriginal))

# Convert to lower case
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, content_transformer(tolower))

# Remove URLs
removeURL <- function(x) gsub("http[^[:space:]]*", "", x)
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, content_transformer(removeURL))

# Remove anything other than English letters or space 
removeNumPunct <- function(x) gsub("[^[:alpha:][:space:]]*", "", x) 
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, content_transformer(removeNumPunct))

# Add extra stopwords
myStopwords <- c(stopwords('english'),"im", "just", "one","youre", 
"hes","shes","its","were","theyre","ive","youve","weve","theyve","id")

# Remove stopwords from corpus
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, removeWords, myStopwords)

# Remove extra whitespace
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, stripWhitespace)

# Remove other languages or more specifically anything with a non "a-z""0-9" character
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, content_transformer(function(s){
gsub(pattern = '[^a-zA-Z0-9\\s]+',
   x = s,
   replacement = " ",
   ignore.case = TRUE,
   perl = TRUE)}))

# Replace word elongations using the textclean package by Tyler Rinker. 
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, replace_word_elongation)

# Creating data frame from corpus 
corpus_asdataframe<-data.frame(text = sapply(corpus, as.character),stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# Due to pre-processing some rows are empty. Therefore, the empty rows should be removed.

# Remove empty rows from data frame and "NA's"
corpus_asdataframe <-corpus_asdataframe[!apply(is.na(corpus_asdataframe) | corpus_asdataframe == "", 1, all),]
corpus_asdataframe<-as.data.frame(corpus_asdataframe)

# Create corpus of clean data frame
corpus <- Corpus(VectorSource(corpus_asdataframe$corpus_asdataframe))
```

So now the issue is that there are a lot of Spanish or German comments in my corpus, which I would like to exclude. I thought that maybe it is possible to download an English dictionary and maybe use an `inner join`to detect english words and remove all other languages. However, I am **very** new to coding (I am studying Business Administration and never had to do anything with computer science) and so my skills are not sufficient for applying my idea to my corpus (or data frame). I really hope find a little help here. That would me very much appreciated! Thank you and best regards from Germany!

Answer (score 0):

```
dftest <- data.frame(
       id = 1:3,
       text = c(
         "Holla this is a spanish word",
         "English online here",
         "Bonjour, comment ça va?"
      ) 
      )
library("cld3")
subset(dftest, detect_language(dftest$text) == "en")

##   id                         text
## 1  1 Holla this is a spanish word
## 2  2          English online here
```

CREDIT: Ken Benoit at: [Find in a dfm non-english tokens and remove them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65274104/find-in-a-dfm-non-english-tokens-and-remove-them)

Comment: Thanks Stanislav Ivanov. This was my first post on stack overflow. Even though I followed instructions , it was really looking ugly. Thanks for tidying up. Will try to do better next time.