# Find in a dfm non-english tokens and remove them

Tags: r, quanteda

In a dfm how is it possible to detect non english words and remove them?

```
dftest <- data.frame(id = 1:3, 
                     text = c("Holla this is a spanish word", 
                              "English online here", 
                              "Bonjour, comment ça va?"))
```

Example the construction of dfm is this:

```
testDfm <- dftest$text %>%
             tokens(remove_punct = TRUE, remove_numbers = TRUE, remove_symbols = TRUE)  %>%  %>% tokens_wordstem() %>%
             dfm()
```

I found textcat package as an alterative solution but there are many case in a real dataset where a whole row which is in the English language it recognize it as another language only for a character. Is there any alternative to find non-English rows in a dataframe or token in the dfm using quanteda?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question is not entirely clear as to whether you want to remove non-English "rows" first, or remove non-English words later.  There are a lot of cognates between European languages (words that are homographs appearing in more than one language) so the `tokens_keep()` strategy will be imperfect.

You could remove the non-English documents after detecting the language, using the **cld3** library:

```r
dftest <- data.frame(
  id = 1:3,
  text = c(
    "Holla this is a spanish word",
    "English online here",
    "Bonjour, comment ça va?"
  )
)
library("cld3")
subset(dftest, detect_language(dftest$text) == "en")
##   id                         text
## 1  1 Holla this is a spanish word
## 2  2          English online here
```

And then input that into `quanteda::dfm()`.

Comment: It is both cases. If we have already the dfm and it contains only the bigrams and trigrams where the words separated by underscore, is it possible to make it? Thank you very much your the nice library you have created

Answer (score 5):

You can do this using a word list of all English words. One place where this exists is in the `hunspell` pacakges, which is meant for spell checking.

```
library(quanteda)
# find the path in which the right dictionary file is stored
hunspell::dictionary(lang = "en_US")
#> <hunspell dictionary>
#>  affix: /home/johannes/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.0/hunspell/dict/en_US.aff 
#>  dictionary: /home/johannes/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.0/hunspell/dict/en_US.dic 
#>  encoding: UTF-8 
#>  wordchars: ’ 
#>  added: 0 custom words

# read this into a vector
english_words <- readLines("/home/johannes/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.0/hunspell/dict/en_US.dic") %>% 
# the vector contains extra information on the words, which is removed
  gsub("/.+", "", .)

# let's display a sample of the words
set.seed(1)
sample(english_words, 50)
#>  [1] "furnace"          "steno"            "Hadoop"           "alumna"          
#>  [5] "gonorrheal"       "multichannel"     "biochemical"      "Riverside"       
#>  [9] "granddad"         "glum"             "exasperation"     "restorative"     
#> [13] "appropriate"      "submarginal"      "Nipponese"        "hotting"         
#> [17] "solicitation"     "pillbox"          "mealtime"         "thunderbolt"     
#> [21] "chaise"           "Milan"            "occidental"       "hoeing"          
#> [25] "debit"            "enlightenment"    "coachload"        "entreating"      
#> [29] "grownup"          "unappreciative"   "egret"            "barre"           
#> [33] "Queen"            "Tammany"          "Goodyear"         "horseflesh"      
#> [37] "roar"             "fictionalization" "births"           "mediator"        
#> [41] "resitting"        "waiter"           "instructive"      "Baez"            
#> [45] "Muenster"         "sleepless"        "motorbike"        "airsick"         
#> [49] "leaf"             "belie"
```

Armed with this vector which should, in theory, contain all English words but only words in English, we can remove non-English tokens:

```
testDfm <- dftest$text %>%
  tokens(remove_punct = TRUE, remove_numbers = TRUE, remove_symbols = TRUE)  %>%
  tokens_keep(english_words, valuetype = "fixed") %>% 
  tokens_wordstem() %>%
  dfm()

testDfm
#> Document-feature matrix of: 3 documents, 9 features (66.7% sparse).
#>        features
#> docs    this a spanish word english onlin here comment va
#>   text1    1 1       1    1       0     0    0       0  0
#>   text2    0 0       0    0       1     1    1       0  0
#>   text3    0 0       0    0       0     0    0       1  1
```

As you can see, this works pretty well but isn't perfect. The "va" from "ça va" has been picked up as an English word as has "comment". What you want to do is thus a matter of finding the right word list and/or cleaning it. You can also think about removing texts in which too many words have been removed.

Comment: thank you. In windows do you know where can I find the path "/home/johannes/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.0/hunspell/"?

Comment: That's why I run `hunspell::dictionary(lang = "en_US")` first :) it will show you the exact location!