# identify elements with specific language, f.e. chinese

Tags: r, nlp, cjk, quanteda

I have a dataset that looks simplified similar to this:

```
call_id<- c("001","002","003","004","005","012","024")
transcript <- c("All the best and happy birthday",
                "万事如意，生日快乐",
                "See you tomorrow",
                "Nice hearing from you",
                "再相见",
                "玩",
                "恭喜你 ")
df <- as.data.frame(cbind(call_id, transcript))
```

I need a code that gives me the call_id or row numbers for the observations where the transcript column includes chinese language. My final goal is to exclude the rows where the transcript column contains chinese language. As I have a data set with 250,000 observation, obviously it must be a code that does this automatically, not one that does this by hand for this small data set. I have already done some analysis with Quanteda. Is there any possibility in Quanteda for this ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I solved it with the cld3 package. See the following https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65274104/find-in-a-dfm-non-english-tokens-and-remove-them

Answer (score 2):

How about using the Unicode character class for Chinese characters?

```
> txt <- c("All the best and happy birthday", "万事如意，生日快乐")
> stringi::stri_detect_regex(txt, "\\p{Han}")
[1] FALSE  TRUE
```

Comment: is there also an expression for non-english?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`textcat`](https://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v052i06) package in `R` to detect multiple languages. It can detect upto 74 languages and uses a reduced n-gram approach designed to remove redundancies of the original approach.

Here's an example to remove rows having `Chinese` language-

```
library("textcat")
out_df <- df[textcat(df$transcript) != "chinese",]
```

Comment: for the original data set it gives me following error:                                                   In textcnt(x, n = max(n), split = split, tolower = tolower, marker = marker,  :
  cleaning up stale state

Comment: This is a warning. Are you getting any errors?

Comment: no, I let it run for 2 hours, but nothing happens. When I interrupt it, the warning comes up.